# How to directly include SVG as a html partial in Go

Tags: svg, go

I want to include svg files as a html partial so I can use it inline in my HTML.
I now I have my svg wrapped in html files and include them like this:

```
{{ template "/partial/my-svg.html" }}
```

But I want to include my svg's directly. PHP does this like so:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("/partial/my-svg.svg"); ?>
```

I don't think go has something similar? So I think I need to extend the template logic with a custom function. Something like:

```
{{ includeSvg "/partial/my-svg.svg" }}
```

How would such a function look like in go?

Comment: What template engine are you using? Default one? If you are using default, my suggestion will be to read SVG file as variable and pass it to template. You can find more information here:

https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/07.4.html

Comment: you also could define a function which would read the path as a file, and print the content, [see this](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs). Be aware that you ll need to wrap the result into a `template.HTML("string")` [type](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML) to avoid html encoding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of how to add a template function and include an svg by path in a template

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func IncludeHTML(path string) template.HTML {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("includeHTML - error reading file: %v", err)
        return ""
    }

    return template.HTML(string(b))
}

func main() {
    tmpl := template.New("sample")
    tmpl.Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "IncludeHTML": IncludeHTML,
    })

    tmpl, err := tmpl.Parse(`
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Check out this svg</h1>
    {{ IncludeHTML "/path/to/svg" }}
</body>
</html>
    `)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
        if err := tmpl.Execute(w, nil); err != nil {
            log.Println("Error executing template: %v", err)
        }
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```